# Emulator sends get request to google every time at startup

Tags: android, android-emulator, burp

I launched [burp](http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html) as an emulator's proxy for debugging of http requests from my application with intercepting option switched on and at the startup I found that emulator sends a `GET` request to google:

```
GET /generate_204 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.3; sdk Build/JWR66V)
Host: 173.194.32.129
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

And gets a response like:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 05 Sep 2013 06:56:51 GMT
Server: GFE/2.0
```

So I would like to know if there is some purpose for making this request to google at the startup?

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely for counting things:

- active developers
- emulator use
- framework use
- generating statistics how developers are spread over the world
- ...

Comment: I firstly thought that it's just for getting time information but then really suspected something strange.

Comment: It turns out, that google is using /generate_204 for a lot of clients. Even google's JS code does that.

Answer (score 0):

It's Android trying to tell if the Wifi (or other network connection) connection has internet. I'm testing on real devices and it does the same thing. If you don't forward the message the connection status in Android Wifi Setting will say "Connected. No internet" until you forward and it gets a success back.